# VBA RegEx Excel - switch on multiple patern matches

Tags: regex, vba, excel, switch-statement

I would like the function to search for the patterns (D2,D3,D4,D5,T2,T3,T4). They all have assigned values to them, so for example D5 has to be 2.4.

In Java I would use switch statement but I'm very new to VBA so I can't wrap my head around this problem. It seems simple but I can't think of a way to do it.

In pseudocode it would be something like that:

```
if myRange.Value contains D4
   result = 2.0
if myRange.Value contains T4
   result = 1.6
```

etc.

Is there a way to do it with some form of Regex check and VBA's equivalent of switch statement?

Thanks

Comment: There's not even a requirement for VBA.  You could set up a table and use VLOOKUP.  Or, if you have to use VBA, you could enter the pattern and values into an array, and iterate through the array to get the result using either Instr or Like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for Regex for such a simple thing. You can use `INSTR()` For example

```
If InStr(1, myRange.Value, "D4", vbTextCompare) Then
    result = 2
ElseIf InStr(1, myRange.Value, "T4", vbTextCompare) Then
    result = 1.6
End If
```

**Recommended for further reading**

[InStr Function](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/InStr-Function-85d3392c-3b1c-4232-bb18-77cd0cb8a55b)

EDIT

If `D4` is not a string then remove the double quotes from the above example "D4"